# Magento 1.9.3.6 Product Image uploaded but not save

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload

Suddenly My store stop to save product image. Product image uploaded successfully but not save and add in list. also radio button not selected. I dont know what is problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time expert,

Actually Issue with the memory limit. IS 256M i have increase this up to 2048M and its work like charm.